# Android Resource Problems

Tags: android

I have two images of same resolution (around 1625*650). One image is around 15Mb and the second image is around 1.5 MB. Now the strange thing is that, placing one image and removing the second one does not seem to have any affect on the APK size? Why is this. Secondly, does a smaller image in terms of disk size mean a smaller memory footprint ?

Kind Regards

Comment: on memory and bitmaps ... http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: But what about the size of the APK ? Smaller image should mean a smaller APK ?

Comment: dont know.. do a verbose build and see log of exactly what is included in the apk... goto ../sdk/tools/ant and change the build.xml.verbose to 'true' ....     <!-- Verbosity -->
    <property name="verbose" value="false" />

Comment: I am not completely sure but I think images are preprocessed before they are packaged into the apk.